# One single background for the UISlider Track

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uislider

I have a custom UISlider for the timerposition of a podcast which is currently (because I don't know better) separated in a left and a right block of the sliding track (135x48 pts) and a custom slider-knob (7x48 pts).

Unfortunately, the way my code is set up it doesn't work properly. 
Although it works, the left half of the slider is moving with the progress of the podcast and the right half gets squeezed after 50% of the slidertrack is reached.

What am I doing awfully wrong here? Do I need a single background for the UISlider Track (270x48 pts)? Is this done by `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`? And how? Or am I way off?

And maybe someone knows how to make this beauty a real screamer by attaching a Sound for the Slider everytime it's moved.

Next is the code. Thank's Guys!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPodcast" ofType:@"mp3"];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
player.delegate = self;
timeSlider.maximumValue = player.duration;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(timeLoader) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

// Setup custom slider images
UIImage *minImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PodcastSliderLeft"];
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PodcastSliderRight"];
UIImage *TImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"PodcastTuner"];

minImage=[minImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
maxImage=[maxImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

// Setup the slider
[timeSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[timeSlider setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[timeSlider setThumbImage:TImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

timeSlider.continuous = NO;

// Cleanup
minImage = nil;
maxImage = nil;
TImage = nil;

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```